# Why cannot use new keyword to initialize abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, interface, new-operator, abstract

I have read somewhere that we cannot initialize an interface, for example:

```
interface MyInterface{};
```

And the following code is definitely illegal:

```
MyInterface m = new MyInterface();
```

And as I remember the text I have read said: that because the `new` keyword is used to allocate memory for class members; so in case of interface, we only have abstract functions, so there is nothing to be allocated in an interface; therefore, initializing an interface is prohibited.

OK, that makes sense to me.

But in case of abstract class, we are allowed to declare and define abstract functions, non-abstract function, as well as normal variables;so why we also are not allowed to initialize an abstract class? And because of that, I was wondering when and how variables in an abstract class, if any, are allocated memory?

Comment: they are allocated when its subclass call super()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No object is ever an instance of "just" an abstract class - it's always an instance of a *concrete* class. Otherwise you could call the abstract methods... and there'd be no implementation to be called.

The variables in an abstract class are allocated the same way as the variables of any other class which happens to be a superclass of the *actual* class being initialized - they live "with" the variables from the other classes in the hierarchy, basically.

EDIT: To clarify, this is a *conceptual* limitation as much as an *implementation* one. An abstract class *usually* contains abstract methods, which is the reason for making it abstract. The point of abstract methods is to allow the caller to have compile-time checking that the method will be there, even though the abstract class doesn't provide the implementation. The VM ensures that there *is* an implementation by preventing instantiation of "just" abstract classes.

Now abstract classes can *also* be used to prevent instantiation even if there aren't any abstract methods - basically the fundamental point of an abstract class is that it's one which *can't* be directly instantiated; only concrete subclasses can be instantiated.

Comment: What if you had an abstract class with only static (and defined) member functions? There's no technical reason you shouldn't be allowed to call those member functions, but semantically the class is still abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Static members do not belong to any instance. You call them like this: `FileUtils.readFile(fileName)` for example. You don't need an instance.

Comment: @Petar: I know, but that wasn't my point. What I mean is that you can take a perfectly legitimate class and decree it to be "abstract", and you can no longer instantiate it. Abstractness is a semantic property of the design, not a technical consequence of physical implementation details. This answer suggests that abstractness has something to do with the specific lack of some implementation.

Comment: @Kerrek: The lack of method implentations isn't a limitation of the implementation though - it's a *conceptual* limitation. You're simply not allowed to have an object where you can call methods which don't exist... and an abstract class is meant to guarantee that the methods *will* exist on any instance, because the instance has to be of a concrete class.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Fair enough:) The lack of some implementation is 99% of the use cases of abstract classes, but you are technically correct that Jon's answer could be a little bit more precise:)

Comment: @Jon: Hm, maybe we're talking in opposite directions. Your point is true of course, but my objection is that your answer seems to be suggesting that the it is the lack of method implementations that *causes* a class to be abstract (conceptually), while I contend that being abstract is a higher-level concept. And after all, as you said, *any* object instance will have all its member functions exists, otherwise you couldn't instantiate it in the first place, you don't need a separate language concept to ensure that. Abstract should really just mean "conceptually abstract"...

Comment: (... and practically it could entail that the compiler won't ask you to implement methods, or even warn you if you do.) ... Good stuff with the edit, have some rep :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: I would say that abstract methods was probably the original motivation for the concept of abstract classes being created in the first place. Put it this way: without abstract methods, do you think there's enough value in the concept of a not-directly-instantiable class to make it worthwhile? I agree that there are uses for abstract classes without abstract methods, of course.

Comment: @Jon: Are you asking me if a specific Java design decision was made in good judgement? :-) One could maybe contrive something where inheriting a bunch of predefined methods and objects may be useful, while an instance of that base wouldn't make sense, but of course that's far-fetched... at gunpoint I would probably argue that the "interface" keyword is more useful than the "abstract" keyword for classes, and "abstract" could have been reserved for member functions only...

Answer (score 5):

When you say "initialize" you really mean two separate things: Allocation and construction. Allocation is the process of obtaining memory for the object; construction is the process of putting bringing the object itself to life.

As you observe rightly, your interface class requires no memory. But that's not the point. An abstract class cannot be *constructed* because it is... well, abstract. There is no *object* of abstract type. And interfaces are abstract.

Think of a Mercedes being an abstract Car. You can buy a Mercedes, but you cannot buy an abstract car - it doesn't make semantic sense. Any car you could conceivably have has to be of a concrete type.

---

Edit: It might be useful to contemplate *why* a class may be abstract:

- Because it is declared `abstract class`. This makes it abstract flat-out by decree, no reason given.
- Because it has abstract member functions: The member function isn't implemented, and a concrete, derived class must provide the implementation.
- Because it is declared `interface`: This is morally equivalent to "all member functions are abstract, and there are no member objects". (Having a separate keyword for this allows interfaces to circumvent the limitations of single inheritance.)

Answer (score 3):

That's the point of an abstract class: to be the base class for other classes. It is specifically designed to *not* be instantiated.

Most abstract classes has abstract methods, which *do not* have implementations. How would you call such a method if you instantiated the abstract class itself?

When you use `new` to create a new instance of a subclass of an abstract class, the memory required for the base abstract class will be allocated then as well.

Answer (score 3):

An **abstract** class is a class which is **not finished yet** and generally has abstract members(although it is not obligatory). So you cannot instantiate an abstract class. This is defined by the language.

Answer (score 1):

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. **Abstract classes cannot be instantiated**,
>   but they can be subclassed.
>
> If a class includes abstract methods, the class itself must be
>   declared abstract.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: @mre If he does, he would understand that it's always an instance of a concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

abstract classes are not full. they have abstract methods, which are not implemented.
what will happen if you try to invoke one of them?

abstract class' variables are located on memory by the concrete instantiated class.

Comment: To be precise an abstract class doesn't need to have any abstract members:)

Answer (score 0):

The variables in an abstract class are allocated when the `new` keyword is used on a class that `extends` the abstract class.

So if you don't have a class extending your abstract class they never get allocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a class, you're allocating memory for several aspects of the class, including an area for methods (it's significantly more involved than this).  Abstract classes do not have definitions for some methods, so we cannot put pointers to actual methods.

Abstract classes contain -- at least partially -- methods without definitions.  You can't call those, because there's no code to run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an illustration with some code could be useful.

```
abstract class AC{
    abstract public void m();
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        AC obj = new AC();
        obj.m();  /* Nothing to execute. */
    }
}
```

So this behavior must be forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, even if your interface is empty, you would have to provide an empty implementation:

Serializable x = new Serializable(){};

The empty curly braces will be needed for an abstract class too. I can't think of encountering a need for these constructs though.